# El Capitan dock and cdock 2 problem

Tags: macos, dock

After updating [cdock 2](https://github.com/w0lfschild/cDock2) to the latest version on my Mac running El Capitan, all the icons moved up from center and now look like on the image below.

How can I fix this?[image]

Answer (score 1):

## Reported and…

This has been reported to the developers as [ticket 23](https://github.com/w0lfschild/cDock2/issues/23):

> With the latest release of cDock2 the icons are up too high on the Dock, making contact wit the top edge of the Dock. See image.
>
> [image]

Given this is an open source application, consider [donating to the cDock maintainer](https://www.paypal.me/w0lfspapa). They will likely respond better if their efforts are rewarded.

### …fixed in v0.10.4

The developer has [responded to the bug report](https://github.com/w0lfschild/cDock2/issues/23#issuecomment-182740303) saying it is now fixed:

> Reverted in 0.10.4